# How to host Django localhost application no openshift?

Tags: django, cloud, openshift, cloud-hosting, pythonanywhere

I have create a Django application in my localhost.Now i need to host in the internet.I have tried [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) and [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) also.But hosting is not easy as i thought.How can i host localhost application in cloud?

Comment: we can't debug this question.! the ans live in google. Or try more specific..

Comment: send us an email to support@pythonanywhere.com, and we'll help you get your site up and running :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the links and description,  you can learn and start.

**PythonAnywhere**

> PythonAnywhere is an online Integrated Development Environment (IDE) and Web hosting service based on the Python programming language.
>
> It provides in-browser access to server-based Python and Bash Command-line interfaces, along with a code editor with Syntax highlighting.

**https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoTutorial**

**OpenShift**

> OpenShift is a cloud computing platform as a service product from Red Hat. A version for private cloud is named OpenShift Enterprise.
>
> The software that runs the service is open-sourced under the name OpenShift Origin, and is available on GitHub. Developers can use Git to deploy web applications in different languages on the platform.

**https://github.com/openshift/django-example**

**Heroku**

> Heroku is a cloud platform as a service (PaaS) supporting several programming languages. Heroku was acquired by Salesforce.com in 2010. Heroku, one of the first cloud platforms, has been in development since June 2007, when it supported only the Ruby programming language, but has since added support for Java, Node.js, Scala, Clojure, Python and PHP and (undocumented) Perl. The base operating system is Debian or, in the newest stack, the Debian-based Ubuntu.

**https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django**

**Gondor**

ref link: `https://gondor.io/support/django/setup/`

sources: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this github example, it lets you run the tutorial locally and then push to Openshift w/o any changes.

https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django16