# django could not find database in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, database, ubuntu

In my settings I have:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost', 
    'PORT': '3306',        
}
```

}

I am using virtual environment and I have used MySQL-python. 
I want to deploy my website and in my control panel I have a place where I have to put my database. I want to put my database in database section of my control panel. I am new to ubuntu and I dont know where I can find this database so that I can put it in there...

Can anyone tell me where can I inspect and find my database??
Also what are the settings to be done while deploying in database ??
Really neeeded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where can I inspect and find my database??

```
mysql -u aaeronn -p aaeronn09
```

Then list all database using

```
mysql> show databases;
```

Where you want to deploy ? please see this link for [deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/)

Comment: thanks for the help that worked but I could not find the directory from where I can copy it..

Comment: @Aaeronn  tell what you want to copy ?

Comment: I havent deployed any website till now so wanted help.. I have set mysql as database. I want to copy that database in the database section of cpanel. Is this the right way or I have to try another way.. take my database from my machine and put into cpanel..

Comment: that's may be right way but tell me more about your cpanel hosting. I don't think you can host your django app to shared hosting service.

Comment: yes you can ! but some good( `google appengine`, `heroku` & `openshift` out there special for python project) service out there please considered that( see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541245/how-to-host-django-localhost-application-no-openshift/25542066#25542066)). In your case please consult with your hosting provider and also see this link ([shared-hosting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache)).

Answer (score 0):

if your looking to copy your database you need to:

`mysqldump -uaaeronn -paaeronn09 eclinicnepal > eclinicnepal.sql`

then upload that sql file to your production/next machine and do

`mysql -uaaeronn -paaeronn09 eclinicnepal < eclinicnepal.sql`

this assumes the production/new machine has the same mysql user and database setup already.